# CSS selector for firefox resize window corner

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, xul

I want to use CSS to make a userstyle for stylish that would change the appearance of the "resize window corner" element. I don't know which selector to use.
scrollcorner works only if there are both vertical and horizontal scrollbars present.
Some example screenshots:

[image]

only horizontal scrollbar - the resize corner is white

[image]

only vertical scrollbar - the resize corner is white

[image]

both scrollbars present - the resize corner is properly styled using the CSS code:

```
scrollcorner{-moz-appearance: none !important;  background: red !important;}
```

Answer (score 3):

We are talking about implicitly created element frames here which makes things complicated to investigate - they are not present in the DOM so not even DOM Inspector will show them. However, the element you are looking for is apparently a [`xul:resizer` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/resizer). I seems that if only one scroll bar (also an implicitly created element frame) is present then this element will be a child of this scroll bar. In the case of two scroll bars a `scrollcorner` element frame is created as a parent for the resizer. I guess that the correct selector would be this:

```css
browser resizer
{
  ...
}
```

This one will only style the resizer belonging to the browser element, not any other resizers like text area resizers.

A warning: I guess that you are registering a new agent stylesheet, because other stylesheets (like user stylesheets for example) will not apply to implicit nodes. You should be careful with that, this is explicitly [not safe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service#Using_the_API) and unexpected styles here might cause browser crashes (see [bug 541506](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=541506) for an example of such issue).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't test this as I've since upgraded from OS X 10.6 to 10.8 and the resizer in firefox is not present here. If someone could test and confirm this in OS X 10.6 I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dom Inspector. (I can't verify the selector, since I don't have mac).

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/?src=search

You'll want to inspect the 'chrome'.

Comment: It's an implicitly created node, DOM Inspector doesn't show it (just as it doesn't show the scrollbars themselves).